# How to import zip image folder as data in a cnn model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, kaggle, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run a basic cnn model on cats vs dogs images.The images exist as zip file.How can we extract the images in the zip folder to a directory using the kaggle online notebook?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKOg3.png)

Comment: use the unzip command and show the path where to extract the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try unzipping it :

```py
!unzip "filePath"
```